# Is "-moz-box-shadow" supported by Firefox / Gecko only recently?

Tags: firefox, shadow, gecko, dropshadow

How well is `-moz-box-shadow` supported by Firefox?  I thought I heard of it for quite some time but the page

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/-moz-box-shadow

says that it is not supported until Firefox 3.5 and Gecko 1.9.1? (with current Firefox 3.6.12 and Gecko 1.9.2)  So it is not supported until recently, is that true?

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on your definition of recent.  Firefox 3.5 was released on June 30, 2009.  It's also the oldest browser supported by Mozilla (has not reached end of life yet, but probably will shortly after Firefox 4 is released).